# Meaning of 'High', 'Low' and 'Unsigned' ledger height status in the Network tab of Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I'm using [Hyperledger Explorer](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/explorer) to view my [Hyperledger Fabric](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/fabric) network information.

In the *Network* tab, there are 3 subcoulumns of *Ledger Height* that I couldn't comprehend: **High**, **Low** and **Unsigned**.

For example, my network has 7 blocks and 4 peers. Each peer displayed these info in the *Network* tab:

- Ledger Height **High** = 0
- Ledger Height **Low** = 7
- Ledger Height **Unsigned** = true

[image]

Could you please elaborate their meanings?

Answer (score 1):

They seems to be numbers which converted from int64 because in javaScript there are no full 64 bit numbers. It's just expressing block heighs which is originally 64bit length by dividing 2 32bit lenght value.

- High: Upper 32bit
- Low:  Lower 32bit
- Unsigned: signed(false) or not(true)